# iOS YUV 420v using GL_TEXTURE_2D shows wrong colour in OpenGL shader

Tags: ios, opengl-es, shader, yuv

**Goal**: To use GL_TEXTURE_2D instead of CVOpenGLESTextureRef to push the YUV data (format is '**420v**' **kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange**) to the shaders (why? Because I need to use glTexSubImage2d to manipulate pixels, and I can't use that with the target being `CVOpenGLESTextureGetTarget(<name>)`, it has no effect. I must use GL_TEXTURE_2D)

**Problem:**
I am using a custom video compositor to manipulate an AVPlayer video. When I use CVOpenGLESTextureRef like in Apple's **AVCustomEdit** sample code, which uses 2 separate shaders, one for Y (luma) and one for UV (chroma), video looks normal like this:

[image]

But trying to use GL_TEXTURE_2D instead makes video just show green and pink colors like this:

[image]

And like this if I use the GL_TEXTURE_2D with the fragment shader that combines both Y and UV textures it looks even worse like this: [image]

My code:

First the track buffer and destination buffer are created:

```
CVPixelBufferRef foregroundSourceBuffer = [request sourceFrameByTrackID:currentInstruction.foregroundTrackID];
CVPixelBufferRef dstBuffer = [_renderContext newPixelBuffer];
```

Then they get passed to the render function which contains the following relevant code:

```
CVOpenGLESTextureRef foregroundLumaTexture  = [self lumaTextureForPixelBuffer:foregroundPixelBuffer];
CVOpenGLESTextureRef foregroundChromaTexture = [self chromaTextureForPixelBuffer:foregroundPixelBuffer];
CVOpenGLESTextureRef destLumaTexture = [self lumaTextureForPixelBuffer:destinationPixelBuffer];       
CVOpenGLESTextureRef destChromaTexture = [self chromaTextureForPixelBuffer:destinationPixelBuffer];
```

The luma texture function returns this:

```
CVOpenGLESTextureRef luma = CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                   _videoTextureCache,
                                                   pixelBuffer,
                                                   NULL,
                                                   GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                                                   GL_RED_EXT,
                                                   (int)CVPixelBufferGetWidth(pixelBuffer),
                                                   (int)CVPixelBufferGetHeight(pixelBuffer),
                                                   GL_RED_EXT,
                                                   GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                                                   0,
                                                   &lumaTexture);
```

The chroma texture function returns this:

```
CVOpenGLESTextureRef chroma = CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                   _videoTextureCache,
                                                   pixelBuffer,
                                                   NULL,
                                                   GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                                                   GL_RG_EXT,
                                                   (int)CVPixelBufferGetWidthOfPlane(pixelBuffer, 1),
                                                   (int)CVPixelBufferGetHeightOfPlane(pixelBuffer, 1),
                                                   GL_RG_EXT,
                                                   GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                                                   1,
                                                   &chromaTexture);
```

Now the relevant body of the render function:

```
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, self.offscreenBufferHandle);

    glViewport(0, 0, (int)CVPixelBufferGetWidthOfPlane(destinationPixelBuffer, 0), (int)CVPixelBufferGetHeightOfPlane(destinationPixelBuffer, 0));


#ifdef USE_GL_TEXTURE_2D

    int bufferWidth = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(foregroundPixelBuffer);
    int bufferHeight = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(foregroundPixelBuffer);


    GLuint frameTextureY;
    GLuint frameTextureUV;

    glGenTextures(1, &frameTextureY);
    glGenTextures(1, &frameTextureUV);


    if(CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(foregroundPixelBuffer, 0) == kCVReturnSuccess){

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, frameTextureY);
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, bufferWidth, bufferHeight, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(foregroundPixelBuffer, 0));

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, frameTextureUV);
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA, bufferWidth/2, bufferHeight/2, 0, GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(foregroundPixelBuffer, 1));

        CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(foregroundPixelBuffer, 0);
    }
#endif

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
#ifdef USE_GL_TEXTURE_2D
    glUseProgram(self.programYUV_2);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, frameTextureY);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(uniforms[UNIFORM_RENDER_TRANSFORM_YUV_2], 1, GL_FALSE, preferredRenderTransform);
#else
    glUseProgram(self.programY);
    glBindTexture(CVOpenGLESTextureGetTarget(foregroundLumaTexture), CVOpenGLESTextureGetName(foregroundLumaTexture));
    glUniformMatrix4fv(uniforms[UNIFORM_RENDER_TRANSFORM_Y], 1, GL_FALSE, preferredRenderTransform);
#endif
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);


    // Attach the destination texture as a color attachment to the off screen frame buffer
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, CVOpenGLESTextureGetTarget(destLumaTexture), CVOpenGLESTextureGetName(destLumaTexture), 0);

    if (glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to make complete framebuffer object %x", glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER));
        goto bail;
    }

    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

#ifdef USE_GL_TEXTURE_2D
    glUniform1i(uniforms[UNIFORM_TEXTURE_YUV_2_Y], 0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(ATTRIB_VERTEX_Y_UV_INONESHADER, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, quadVertexData1);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIB_VERTEX_Y_UV_INONESHADER);
    glVertexAttribPointer(ATTRIB_TEXCOORD_Y_UV_INONESHADER, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, quadTextureData1);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIB_TEXCOORD_Y_UV_INONESHADER);
#else
    glUniform1i(uniforms[UNIFORM_TEXTURE_Y], 0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(ATTRIB_VERTEX_Y, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, quadVertexData1);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIB_VERTEX_Y);
    glVertexAttribPointer(ATTRIB_TEXCOORD_Y, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, quadTextureData1);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIB_TEXCOORD_Y);
#endif
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 5);


    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
#ifdef USE_GL_TEXTURE_2D
    //no need to use different program
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, frameTextureUV);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(uniforms[UNIFORM_RENDER_TRANSFORM_YUV_2], 1, GL_FALSE, preferredRenderTransform);
#else
    glUseProgram(self.programUV);
glBindTexture(CVOpenGLESTextureGetTarget(foregroundChromaTexture), CVOpenGLESTextureGetName(foregroundChromaTexture));
    glUniformMatrix4fv(uniforms[UNIFORM_RENDER_TRANSFORM_UV], 1, GL_FALSE, preferredRenderTransform);
#endif
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);


    glViewport(0, 0, (int)CVPixelBufferGetWidthOfPlane(destinationPixelBuffer, 1), (int)CVPixelBufferGetHeightOfPlane(destinationPixelBuffer, 1));

    // Attach the destination texture as a color attachment to the off screen frame buffer
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, CVOpenGLESTextureGetTarget(destChromaTexture), CVOpenGLESTextureGetName(destChromaTexture), 0);

    if (glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to make complete framebuffer object %x", glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER));
        goto bail;
    }

    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

#ifdef USE_GL_TEXTURE_2D
    glUniform1i(uniforms[UNIFORM_TEXTURE_YUV_2_UV], 1);
    glVertexAttribPointer(ATTRIB_VERTEX_Y_UV_INONESHADER, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, quadVertexData1);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIB_VERTEX_Y_UV_INONESHADER);
    glVertexAttribPointer(ATTRIB_TEXCOORD_Y_UV_INONESHADER, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, quadTextureData1);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIB_TEXCOORD_Y_UV_INONESHADER);#else
    glUniform1i(uniforms[UNIFORM_TEXTURE_UV], 1);
    glVertexAttribPointer(ATTRIB_VERTEX_UV, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, quadVertexData1);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIB_VERTEX_UV);
    glVertexAttribPointer(ATTRIB_TEXCOORD_UV, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, quadTextureData1);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIB_TEXCOORD_UV);
#endif

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 5);

    glFlush();

bail:
#ifdef USE_GL_TEXTURE_2D
    glDeleteTextures(1, &frameTextureY);
    glDeleteTextures(1, &frameTextureUV);
#endif
    CFRelease(foregroundLumaTexture);
    CFRelease(foregroundChromaTexture);
    CFRelease(destLumaTexture);
    CFRelease(destChromaTexture);

    // Periodic texture cache flush every frame
    CVOpenGLESTextureCacheFlush(self.videoTextureCache, 0);
```

Here are my fragment shaders, that I use depending on different test cases (whether I draw the Y and UV separately or together in one):

```
static const char kFragmentShaderY[] = {
"varying highp vec2 texCoordVarying; \n \
 uniform sampler2D s_texture_y; \n \
 void main() \n \
 { \n \
    gl_FragColor.r = texture2D(s_texture_y, texCoordVarying).r; \n \
 }"
```

};

```
static const char kFragmentShaderUV[] = {
"varying highp vec2 texCoordVarying; \n \
uniform sampler2D s_texture_uv; \n \
void main() \n \
{ \n \
    gl_FragColor.rg = texture2D(s_texture_uv, texCoordVarying).rg; \n \
}"
```

};

```
static const char kFragmentShaderYUV_2Textures[] = {
"varying highp vec2 texCoordVarying; \n \
uniform sampler2D s_texture_y; \n \
uniform sampler2D s_texture_uv; \n \
\n \
void main() \n \
{ \n \
    mediump vec3 yuv;// = vec3(1.1643 * (texture2D(s_texture_y, texCoordVarying).r - 0.0625), \n \
    lowp vec3 rgb; \n \
    yuv.x = texture2D(s_texture_y, texCoordVarying).r; \n \
    yuv.yz = texture2D(s_texture_uv, texCoordVarying).rg - vec2(0.5, 0.5); \n \
    \n \
    rgb = mat3(      1,       1,       1, \n \
    0, -.21482, 2.12798, \n \
    1.28033, -.38059,       0) * yuv;   \n \
    gl_FragColor = vec4(rgb, 1.0); \n \
}"
```

};

Using GL_TEXTURE_2D, if I use the fragment shader containing both the Y and UV textures, the video looks like #3 above. If I use the two separate fragment shaders (one for Y, one for UV), the picture is #2 above (ALMOST right but the chroma colors are just greens and pinks) *(mind you I do comment out some of the code above to be able to use the 2 separate fragment shaders, and of course I glBind to the GL_TEXTURE_2D and not the CV, and so on, and so on).

Again, my problem is I need to use GL_TEXTURE_2D instead of CVOpenGLESTextureGetTarget, but it doesn't show the right chroma colour if I do. I wonder what I am doing wrong. Is it something to do with the YUV format being kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange instead of kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarFullRange perhaps? I have also experimented with the making 3 GL_LUMINANCE textures method as well, and many other permutations with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the problem was with using GL_LUMINANCE and GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA, which are apparently deprecated formats. When I switched them to GL_RED_EXT and GL_RG_EXT, it worked and the chroma colors are finally right. I hope this question and answer will save other people time.